# Change File extension using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some images in a folder with the .JPG extension. I want to change the image extension to .PNG programmatically. My earlier post is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15428521/read-a-file-extension-and-change-that-extension.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "aa.jpg",
    dataType: "snapshot",
    success: function (snapshot) 
    {
        try
        {
            var src = $(this).attr("url"); 
            $(src).attr('src',$(this).attr('url').replace('.jpg','png'));
        } 
        catch(ex)
        {
            alert(ex);
        }               
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't think this will really work because just changing a file extension doesn't change the file itself.  In this example, the aa.jpg file will STILL be a jpg file, even though it has an extension of png.

Comment: What do you mean change file extension?Change it only on browser or just like renaming the image on the server?

Comment: Just an FYI: As @scott.korin said, changing the file extension does not change the file type. If you are wanting to programmatically change the extension, say in a `<img src="" />` then you can use `substr` or `replace` in javascript. This however, will result in a broken image, nothing more, so it's pointless. If you want to permanently change the extension on the server, which would break the `img` everywhere, it would be impossible without an `ajax` request as JavaScript is client side and cannot modify a file system server side (or client side for that matter).

Answer (score 0):

After reading both your question I realise that you want to rename files on the client.
This cannot be done using jQuery alone. Normal javascript engines do not allow access to filesystems on client side.

You need something a little more powerful - on windows that would be an ActiveX object. If you're on another OS, or a browser which does not support ActiveX, I don't know how to help you.

[Here](http://www.wangarific.com/rewrite-rename-filenames-using-javascript/) you can find an example.